# How did Protagonist know that descendants will kill them?

Tags: tenet

> Sator: The same sunshine we basked in will warm the faces of our
> **descendants** generations to come.
>
> Protagonist: **How could they wanna kill us?**
>
> Sator: Because their oceans rose and their rivers ran dry. Don't you
> see? They have no choice but to turn back.

How did Protagonist know that descendants will kill them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the scene inside the container where Neil, The Protagonist and Kat are talking about the algorithm. As Neil explains what happens when the descendants get the algorithm, he says:

> Our present wiped out, our past obliterated. Everyone and everything who ever lived destroyed instantly. Precise enough?